# get notified when UITextField becomeFirstResponder

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, first-responder, becomefirstresponder

How I can get notified when `UITextField` `becomeFirstResponder` ?

I can check like `isFirstResponder` or set to to become first Responder by `becomeFirstResponder`

I want to get notified or handle an event when a user make this text field first responder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You will need to be come the text field's delegate and implement this optional delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Answer (score 15):

Besides implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, you can register for the `UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` notification.

The notification method could be:

```
- (void)someTextFieldDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)notification.object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The delegate is definitely the way to go. Unfortunately, in my situation I couldn't use that, because the controller was the delegate of my UITextField subclass and I needed to modify it's placeholder text. Instead I override the methods `- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder;` & `- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder;`. Be sure to call super.

Comment: Yeah, your comment to remember to call super solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

For OSX you should be aware of buttons having side effects when relying on the `NSControlTextDidBeginEditingNotification`.

When you start editing, push some buttons, and resume editing the text field, you won't get a second `NSControlTextDidBeginEditingNotification` when you resume editing.

In case this behavior causes a problem, `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` might be an alternative.